# how to concatenate input color image and gradient magnitude in python

Tags: python, concatenation, gradient, magnitude

[concatenated image with gray and gradient magnitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Bej.jpg)

[gradient magnitude image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca93F.jpg)

[input color image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg7ql.png)

i cant concatenate input color image and gradient magnitude

```
input = cv2.imread('figures/output.png')# 3 channel
input.astype(np.float32)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float 
dy = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # 255보다 커질 수 있으므로 saturate 연산

cv2.imshow('magnitude', mag)

addv = cv2.vconcat((input, mag)) # error
```

i get an error that addv part
but `gray = cv2.cvtColor(input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` gray with gradient magnitud concatenating is fine

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-1syr35c1/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_operations.cpp:111: error:
 (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].cols == src[0].cols && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'vconcat'
```

i dont know why

Comment: What does error say?

Comment: error part  =  addv = cv2.vconcat((im, mag)) # error
error message = cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-1syr35c1/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_operations.cpp:111: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].cols == src[0].cols && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'vconcat'

Comment: For vconcat both image should have same number of channels and same width

Comment: i know input image is 3channel and magnitude is no channel so it cant be concatenate   but i have to do i'm coding followed paper "https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Wan_Reflection_Scene_Separation_From_a_Single_Image_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf"

Comment: paper said "we concatenate the input image with its corresponding gradient image as the input to the separation network "

Comment: you mean `cv2.vconcat((img, mag))` right? not `cv2.vconcat((im, mag))` <-- img not im

Comment: no, addv = cv2.vconcat((im, mag)) is right   im=> input color image, mag => gradient magnitude image mag is image ill show you

Comment: What is `im.shape` and `mag.shape`  and `img.shape`?

Comment: im.shape(input color image): (282, 366, 3)
img.shape(input gray image): (282, 366)
mag.shape(gradient magnitude image):  (282, 366)
concatenating input gray image and gradient magnitude image => good
concatenating input color image and gradient magnitude image => error

Comment: That is what i am saying,` vstack` both channel should have the same channels

Comment: how to make both image channel same?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import cv2 
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('figures/output.png')# 3 channel
im.astype(np.float32)
img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)  # float 
dy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)  # gradient magnitude , no channel
mag = np.clip(mag, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # 255보다 커질 수 있으므로 saturate 연산

cv2.imshow('magnitude', mag)
mag = cv2.cvtColor(mag, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) # convert mag to RGB
addv = cv2.vconcat((im, mag))
```